# Getting the jQuery-UI scrolling autocomplete combobox widget to fully work in Meteor

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, meteor

I have managed to get a combination of the jQuery UI combobox autocomplete and scrolling code (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) to work in Meteor with the following steps:

- Download a custom jQuery UI with the smoothness theme. Put it in client/jquery-ui-1.10.3
- Move  client/jquery-ui-1.10.3/css/smoothness/images to public/jquery-ui-1.10.3/css/smoothness/images
- Put the javascript code, without the  (function( $ ) {}) that wraps it, in the client javascript. I also don't include the following code, since it doesn't work (which is why I'm posting this):

`$(function() {
      $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
      $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
        $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
      });
    });`

Put the css in the client css. Put the html in the html.

At this point, the code works, with one exception: I have to manually run $("#combobox").combobox() in the chrome console to get it to render. I have tried, for example, Template.langtwo.rendered = -> $("#combobox").combobox(), however, it doesn't work. In fact, when I do it this way, running it in the chrome console no longer works.

It feels like a timing issue of some sort, but I'm really not sure where to put $("#combobox").combobox()

Another small issue is that it doesn't quite render correctly. As you can see the arrow button is too small. Image: http://ibin.co/18OTxtcOcIp5

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this question here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/B00WuvRtGKs/IICzuLdt0cIJ